# If f(z) is analytic then u(x,y)=Re(f(x+iy)) is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

We have the given statement *If f(z) is analytic then u(x,y)=Re(f(x+iy)) is harmonic*.

In order to prove/disprove it, I use the Cauchy-Riemann equations, since they define analycity:

$u_x=v_y$

$u_y=-v_x$

and the Laplace equation, to prove harmonicity: $u_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$

So,

Laplace equation on $f$ gives $Re[f(z)]_{xx}+Re[fz)]_{yy}=0 $, which is feasible, since $u_{xx}=0=u_{yy}=0$ but then we get a contradiction on the Cauchy-Riemann equations. We set $u=Re[f(x+iy)]=$ and assume that $iv=Im[f(x+iy)]$

$(u)_x=(v)_y$

$(u)_y=-(v)_x $

Then it seems correct?

Any suggestions appreciated

With Thanks

Comment: you cannot set u=x

Comment: Why not, it is the Real part of f(z)

Comment: Did you mean *harmonic*?

Comment: The real part of $f(x+iy)$ is not $x$. – Note also that you have to prove $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$, not $u_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$.

Comment: Why? What is it? f(x)?

Comment: If $f=u+iv$ then the real part of $f$ is simply $u$.

Comment: Ok, then the answer is yes, but it seems that this proof does not really prove anything, only repeat the Laplace and Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: @ViolaPlayer: Yes, the harmonicity of $u$ is an immediate consequence of the CR equations.